# Comparing a the last elements of a List to a 2D list for similarities

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

How can I go through my 2D list to find the words that have similar elements.
For example. I have a 2D list like so:

```
values = [[' T ', ' IH1 ', ' L '], [' T ', ' IH1 ', ' Z '], [' T ', ' W ', ' AH1 ', ' Z '], [' I ', ' IH1 ', ' L ']]

endPhonemes = [' IH1 ', ' L ']
```

How can I iterate through my 2D list to find which inner list **ENDS** with endPhonemes and returns the index number of  the inner list? I tried to use two nested for loops but I can't get the syntax right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `enumerate()` for the task:

```
values = [ [ ' T ' , ' IH1 ' , ' L ' ] , [ ' T ' , ' IH1 ' , ' Z '] , [' T ' , ' W ' , ' AH1 ' , ' Z '] , [' I ' , ' IH1 ' , ' L ' ] ]
endPhonemes = [ ' IH1 ' , ' L ']

print([i for i, v in enumerate(values) if v[-2:]==endPhonemes])
```

Prints:

```
[0, 3]
```